# NullPointerException with Websocket in Processing Sketch

Tags: websocket, nullpointerexception, processing

I have set up an example in Processing which is working fine by utilising the Voice Recognition Library http://florianschulz.info/stt/

I am trying to send the contents of a string to the Draw function and its causing a NullException error when you don't define a default value in void setup

First I though that I should set up a global String msg but no matter how I try to define it it won't update the draw function with anything except the word test. This is because I have defined it inside void setup() as having the value "test"

However if you remove the word test, it causes a null exception error again.

What happens is that the String msg defaults to the value test  but once you speak into the laptop microphone, the console should update the word or sentence  through the text(); function and in turn appear in Processing java window with the updated word.

```java
import websockets.*;
WebsocketServer socket;
PFont f;
String msg;

    void setup() {

      socket = new WebsocketServer(this, 1337, "/p5websocket");
      noLoop();
      size(480, 120);
      f = createFont("Arial",16,true); // Arial, 16 point, anti-aliasing on 
       if (msg == null){
         msg="test";
         println(msg);
      }
      else{
        println(msg);

      }
    }

    void draw() {
      background(100);
      textFont(f,36);
      fill(180);  
      println(msg);
      text(msg, 10, 10, 70, 80);// Text wraps within text box

    }

    void webSocketServerEvent(String msg){

      println(msg);

    }
```

Comment: You’re not assigning any value to `msg` after the “test” so it can’t change anywhere. Did you mean to assign it in the event?

Comment: Thanks, I am not quite sure how to assign it so that it updates within the draw function. Where it says text(msg, 10, 10, 70, 80) is where I want the value that has come from void webSocketServerEvent to update the text that is displayed within the processing java window. Currently it just says test within that window but isn't updating with new info from the websocket.

Comment: The value of msg is being updated within void webSocketServerEvent(String msg){

      println(msg);

    }     because when you speak into the microphone it prints out the result in the console window in processing but its not captured by void draw(){     }

Comment: No, that one is only receiving it and printing it. It’s not being stored anywhere. You might want to add `this.msg = msg;` in that method to actually store it.

Comment: i tried adding that to void setup(), void draw() and void webSocketServer() and none of them made any difference. If you have a statically set variable for msg as in test that appears in the console and a dynamically changing variable (also msg) coming from void websocketServer I can't undestand why one doesn't update the other as its the same String name in both. Should void websocketServer be called in the draw function first before text(msg, 10, 10, 70, 80); using webSocketServer(msg); maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to assign the sketch-level `msg` variable to the value of the `msg` argument passed into the `webSocketServerEvent()` function?

Note that just because they have the same name doesn't mean they're the same variable. They're two different variables in two different scopes. If you want to reference or reassign the sketch-level variable, you can use the `this` keyword to disambiguate:

```
void webSocketServerEvent(String msg){
  this.msg = msg;
  println(msg);
}
```

Or you could just rename one of the variables:

```
void webSocketServerEvent(String webSocketMessage){
  this.msg = webSocketMessage;
  println(msg);
}
```

Comment: I tried both but neither changed the value of the string from "test" in the console. It doesn't seem to matter where you write this.msg = webSocketMessage; the output is always the word "test" in the java window. But voice rec changes the console message to whatever you speak into the mic. I some how need to capture that string rather than the static one defined within void setup()?

Comment: @undesignuk Start with something simpler. Create a sketch that shows "test" by default, and switches it to "clicked" after you click the mouse. Get that working first. If you can't get that working, post your code as a [mcve] in a new question post.